# Running node.js code just displays a node identifier

Tags: node.js

I have the following code in a file called server.js.

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  response.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(8124);

console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8124/');
```

I use the command prompt and naviage to the folder where the file recides and then the run the command

```
node server.js
```

But I don't get the expected output. Instead I get

```
The node identifier for {My Machine Name} is v2hrfnqaj.
```

Note: I already have node installed in my machine and it was working fine.

Comment: WHat happens when you do `node -v`?

Comment: What happens when you go to `http://127.0.0.1:8124/`?

Comment: @Trevor : node -v does't work.. I get the same output

Comment: Have you installed CA Harvest software? Which will conflict with node.exe. Editing the path variable will solve the issue as explained in the answer below: inhttp://stackoverflow.com/a/25925019/3581643

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Was getting this when I was trying to run cordova commands. Steps to resolve:

Windows

1. In CMD prompt, type "where node". As Michael mentioned, this shows
   you the likely culprit, that you have 2 nodejs EXEs installed on
   your machine.
2. Navigate to Start > Computer > Right-click Properties > Advanced system settings
3. Under the Advanced tab, select Environment Variables
4. Under System variables, select "Path" variable
5. Find nodejs EXE, usually "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\"
6. Cut and paste this to the beginning of the "Path" variable. Ensure
   the paths are separated by a ";"
7. Open a new CMD prompt and try cordova again

Comment: Since I did post the initial solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24456503/428628), I think you could've done a bit better to credit me, perhaps adding your solution as a comment to mine. I mention this because you seem fairly new to SO and may be unfamiliar with SO etiquette.

Comment: Unfortunately changing `PATH` will break Harvest SCM. So if you need to work with Node.js *and* check-in your code to Harvest like me, you're doomed. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30979722/1461424) for a better solution.

Answer (score 17):

This happens when [Harvest SCM](https://www.ca.com/us/products/ca-harvest-software-change-manager.html) is installed on your system. It has an executable with the name `node.exe` at `<Program Files (x86)>\CA\SharedComponents\PEC\bin` (where `<Program Files (x86)>` is your x86 program files folder). This path is present in your `PATH` variable *before* the path to Node.js's `node.exe`.

**Update**: You don't need the elaborate scheme listed in the old answer. You just have to open the Command Prompt and run:

```
C:\> nodevars
```

`nodevars.bat` is a small script that does essentially the same thing described below (but in a safer way). If you have node installed, this script should be in path. (If not make sure to add `C:\Program Files\nodejs` to your path. But make sure to append it in the end so Harvest SCM does not break).

---

**Everything below is outdated, but I will leave it for the curious reader.**

You can do either of following two things you can do to overcome this problem:

1. Remove `<Program Files (x86)>\CA\SharedComponents\PEC\bin` from `PATH` environment variable.
2. Add/move `<Program Files (x86)>\nodejs` to the beginning of the `PATH` environment variable (This is the [currently accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25925019/1461424) from [djrpascu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3622178/djrpascu)).

## You can do better!

There are two problems with the above approaches:

1. You break Harvest SCM's functionality.
2. If you do not have elevated privileges to change `PATH`, you are out of options. (Thanks [@Glats](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2291305/glats))

So I created this little batch file, and put it in a directory where I have several other personal scripts (this directory is in my `PATH`). [Here's the gist for the script](https://gist.github.com/sampathsris/719fc733d6d5e98b2b53/).

**`nodecmd.bat`**

```
@echo off

set path=%path:C:\Program Files (x86)\CA\SharedComponents\PEC\bin;=%;C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs;

start %ComSpec%
```

Then the next time you want to run Node.js, instead of Command Prompt, you open the new script with ["Run..." command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run_command).

> <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
>
> `nodecmd`

A command prompt will appear. You can use this command prompt to run `node` without a hassle.

## Explanation

This bit deletes the Harvest's executable's path from `PATH` variable:

```
%path:C:\Program Files (x86)\CA\SharedComponents\PEC\bin;=%;
```

And this adds the Node.js's path:

```
set path=...;C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs;
```

The result is a string that contains the original PATH variable *minus* Harvest's path, *plus* Node's path. And it is set as PATH variable in the scope of current batch file.

> ***Note:*** You might have to change the path's in the script to suit software installation folders in your system).

Next line, `start %ComSpec%` starts a Command Prompt. By this time, the PATH variabe is modified. With modified environment variables, you can run node within this new Command Prompt. **The environment variable modification does not affect the rest of the system**, making sure that Harvest SCM software runs without breaking.

Comment: This is a good solution. I'd recommend adding a bit more clarity on what your approach does, which is "fix" node by executing it with a wrapper script that temporarily fixes the PATH env var. It isn't clear from your answer that you need to always launch node from this new wrapper, and that the PATH change is not permanent, which is key to not breaking Harvest.

Comment: this one worked for me, because I don't have elevated privileges to change my environment path

Answer (score 5):

Don't break your Harvest SCM by removing it from path. Try this one, open your windows command line (cmd) and then pass the following nodejs batch file so that it will set your command line to nodejs environment. Enjoy the node commands there.

C:> "C:\Program Files\nodejs\nodevars.bat"

Answer (score 3):

You can also prioritize  in the environments.
Steps:
Computer -> Right click -> Properties -> Advanced system settings -> Environment variables -> PATH(in system variables list) -> Edit -> Prioritize  by moving up

Answer (score 2):

This is old, but I ran into this same problem. Exact same message (with my machine name of course). The issue was that there was another node executable on the path, in `C:\Program Files (x86)\CA\SharedComponents\PEC\bin`.  I'm on a windows machine, so running `where node` showed the two conflicting "node" executables in the path.

To fix the problem, I just removed the CA directory from the `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Unfortunately changing the `PATH` variable breaks the Harvest SCM.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and simply changed the the name of `node.exe` file from Harvest. This hasn't broken anything from Harvest and I can keep working with it.

Change the Harvest's command name to `node_.exe`:

```
ren "C:\Program Files (x86)\CA\SharedComponents\PEC\bin\node.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\CA\SharedComponents\PEC\bin\node_.exe"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're running the wrong node command.
Try locating or re-downloading your nodejs installation and add it to your path as the first directory. If you're running linux or unix you can try 'which node' to see what is being run.
Note that in some cases, the node.js executable is called nodejs so you may want to try 
`nodejs server.js` as well

Answer (score 0):

I used the node.js command prompt, instead of the windows default command prompt and it worked for me. Did not know why it did't work in the windows default command prompt.

Answer (score -1):

I was also running with same issue - while defining the path for windows use below parameter

Windows:

```
set NODE_PATH=C:\nodejs
```

OR

Set the environment variable for nodejs

```
NODE_PATH=C:\nodejs
Path= C:\nodejs
```

(append the path contain this string “c:\nodejs”)