# Node and Grunt display node identifier message instead of executing

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, npm

I have installed node on my machine and have two executables, node.exe and nodejs.exe in my directory.  Through the NPM I have installed grunt and jshint for grunt; following this guide:

http://strongloop.com/strongblog/use-grunt-js-and-the-power-of-javascript-to-automating-repetitive-tasks/

When I try and run "grunt" "node" or "grunt jshint" into the windows command prompt or Git Bash then I recieve the following response:

```
The node identifier for <machine number> is <id number>
```

I have in my path the location to the \nodejs\node.exe file

I do not have admin or root access to my machine, but can put requests in to add permissions or extra items to the Path.  However, I was able to get JSHint to work in Sublime Text by specifying the node path as "nodejs/nodejs.exe"

Would changing my path to nodejs.exe instead fix this; or is there a deeper issue into the setup I have configured that would be causing this problem?

Comment: What is the response when you type `where node` at the command prompt? I'm wondering if you have another piece of software installed that is earlier in your path that is being executed when node is called.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running node.js code just displays a node identifier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14882427/running-node-js-code-just-displays-a-node-identifier)

Answer (score 1):

check your system %PATH% variable (`echo %PATH%`). Most certainly there is another application called node.bat, node.cmd or node.exe that is in your PATH before nodejs and thats why the system finds this first. I'm 99% sure that this is not the output from nodejs

if you have access to your path try to prepend the nodejs path

Comment: Indeed: C:\PrivateWS\resources\npm-1.4.6\package\bin>where node
returns C:\Program Files (x86)\CA\SharedComponents\PEC\bin\node.exe

Comment: Actually the output is from Harvest SCM's `node.exe`. A solution I found for this is available here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30979722/1461424